# nginx failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream,

Tags: nginx

When uploading files less than 8 MB the upload is fine with my NGINX config. 
Uploading files with ~8MB fails.

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name ~. "";
    location {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Checking the nginx error logs I can see this

```
nginx failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream,
```

This nginx errors then shows `502 Bad Gateway error` to the client.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is with the Upstream server (which is NGINX Unit)
I had to set the `max_body_size` from there and the upload is not working fine.

Bottom line here is to check the Upstream server first.

Related to https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,284631,284631#msg-284631